# Touchscreen on Zero W without X?

Tags: display, pi-zero-w, touchscreen, framebuffer

I'm designing a Raspberry Pi Zero W project with a touchscreen. I want to use [this screen](https://www.waveshare.com/4inch-hdmi-lcd-h.htm). Would there be a way to use the touchscreen on that without having X? I'll be using `/dex/fbX` for the display.

Comment: does your system have `/dev/input` directory? ... if yes, then one of the devices listed there should be the touch panel data

Comment: @jsotola I don't know. I don't have a Pi Zero or the touchscreen yet.